# C# - Change order of Notify Icon in System Tray in Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have requirement to place the Notify Icon next to Battery icon in System tray/Notification area in Windows 10. When I add the icon using "NotifyIcon" type available it adds the Icon to the overflow area of System Tray. I'm developing this tool using C# and please let me know any insight on this.

```
using (NotifyIcon icon = new NotifyIcon())
{
    System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon("./Image/icon.ico");
    icon.Icon = Icon.FromHandle(bmp.GetHicon());
    icon.Text = "See your device health";
    icon.Click += new System.EventHandler(notifyIcon_Click);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should read [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/026113bd-d14c-4a3f-83c0-12c4fbeaf821/how-to-get-the-location-of-notifyicon-at-runtime?forum=csharpgeneral) forum post.

Comment: Thank you Joren and User. I had gone through the forums you posted here and also other forums. Looks like there is no direct Windows API available to perform this and I need to do more research on this.

Answer (score 3):

The order of icons in the taskbar notification area (TNA) is not something you can control programmatically.

Raymond Chen wrote a [blog entry](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180614-00/?p=99015) about it.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your reply